# I cannot add a partial view in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I try to add a partial view using asp.net mvc 3 and razor it just add's a normal .cshtml file and not a partial view. has anyone had this problem before?

/Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Razor there is no notion of partial views as there was in WebForms. You only have templates with the `.cshtml` extension. Depending on how the controller action serves this view (with either `return View()` or `return PartialView()`) the `_Layout.cshtml` will be applied or not. Also if you render a template with either the Html.Partial helper this template will be considered as a partial view. Finally you have the possibility to set whether you want or not a Layout from inside the template itself. For example to disable it:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

So basically in Razor you have templates and you could consider *partial views* as templates without a layout.

Comment: Ok, I kind of knew that, but did not explain my-self good enough then. When I look in the shared folder the login partial starts with an _ that does not happen when i create one or mayby it does not have to do so?

Comment: @websam, the underscore is purely conventional for developers. It has no special meaning in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Ok, but why does it not create the underscore when I add a partial view. When i first have 100 views I don't know what is partial views and what is not ?

Comment: @websam, if this is a functionality that you need don't hesitate to open a ticket for the next version. Microsoft might take it into consideration when designing the VS Tools for ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

Comment: Ok, so i will just have to add an underscore when I add a new partial view that's fine by me. Thank's for your help on this matter ;o)